# Standard Lightning Layout in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, page-layout, lightninginput

I would ask if it is possible to get the same Standard Lightning Experience Layout in a Lightnign Component.

For example I would replicate this Layout:
[image]

but in Lightning Component I am using **lightning:input** component and the result is:

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Referring to [SLDS library](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/getting-started/): You would need to use [Expandable Section](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/expandable-section/), in it use [Form Layout](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-layout/). Layout in 1/2 columns can also be controlled by [Sizing](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/sizing/). Please try and let us know if you are stuck!

Comment: To add to @RahulSharma - you are using `lightning:input` component which is  an input field and in the standard layout you have a read only field only if you click on the pencil you get the edit mode. To achieve this behavior you can use a standard `Related Record` component that it's `Update Action` is an Update Action of the object

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `lightning:layout` and `lightning:layoutItem` to achieve the SLDS grid.

```
<lightning:layout >
    <lightning:layoutItem >
        <lightning:input name="input1" label="First Name"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem >
        <lightning:input name="input2" label="Last Name"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

If you're looking for a read-only record layout, Winter '18 comes with `lightning:outputField`, where you can do something like this.

```
<lightning:recordViewForm recordId="003R0000001b5x1IAA" objectApiName="Contact">
    <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
        <lightning:layout class="slds-p-around--large">
            <lightning:layoutItem >
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Phone"/>
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Email" />
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:layoutItem class="slds-p-around--large">
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="Birthdate" />
                <lightning:outputField fieldName="LeadSource" />
            </lightning:layoutItem>
        </lightning:layout>
    </div>
</lightning:recordViewForm>
```